# GAE - Cannot get html content from PHP "include" to show up, no console output

Tags: php, html, google-app-engine, include

Using Google App Engine, I'm trying to display a PHP page that contains html, within which I have more html content from another source. I'm using a PHP tag to include the content, like so:

< ?php include "https://myfileURL.html"; ?>

But it does not show up in the page source code. The html file is in a "/HTML/" folder which is handled as a static_dir in app.yaml. I can access the URL from the browser and the content is there, but if I put that URL in the include tag I get nothing. I can even put bad URLs and I get no errors, no console output... just nothing. The page displays with white space in the middle of the source code.

Any idea what's going on here? Everything works perfectly in localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Argh... backend process... need to catch errors in php, nevermind.